# Are there other examples of postposed prepositions like in "Meiner Meinung nach, ..."?

Tags: preposition, word-order

Gibt es weitere Beispiele mit einer Präposition am Ende einer Wortgruppe, wie in

> *Meiner Meinung nach, ...*  ?

Comment: "schönen Abend noch"?

Comment: @Explorer "noch" ist leider keine Präposition, sondern ein Partikel: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/noch_schon_mal_doch

Comment: @splattne: Ah , dann soll "ich komme mit" richtig sein?!

Comment: siehe auch: "Preposition Stranding" http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_Stranding

Comment: @Explorer nein, auch nicht. Das vollständige Verb heißt mitkommen. Präpositionen benötigen immer ein Hauptwort.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Beispiele für [Postpositionen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postposition):

- dem Ende *entgegen*
- der Einfachheit *halber*
- der Kinder *wegen*
- …

Und dann gibt es auch noch die [Zirkumposition](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zirkumposition): „*um* des Friedes *willen*“

Comment: Wenn es ein Wort dafür gibt, ... Danke! Ich hätte es wissen sollen.

Comment: Ist zum Ende hin wirklich eine Postposition? (+1 für den Rest)

Comment: @thei Nein, Du hast recht: laut Duden ist es ein Adverb. Ich hab’ jetzt „zum Ende hin“ durch „dem Ende entgegen“ ersetzt, hier ist es definitiv eine Postposition – ist auch logisch (das andere war ja „ *zum* Ende …“) aber zugegebenermaßen kann ich den Unterschied nicht gut erklären.

Answer (score 11):

- dem Alter **entsprechend**
- Gerüchten **zufolge**
- tu's mir **zuliebe**

Dazu auch **halber**, **entgegen**, **entlang**, **gegenüber** und **wegen**...  [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4position#Die_Stellung_der_Pr.C3.A4position) *zufolge*.

Comment: Danke für diese andere Beispiele.